# Thymeleaf Unescaped JavaScript Inlining

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

How can I get **unescaped** JavaScript inlining output with Thymeleaf 3.0.x? Escaped inlining works just fine. Example:

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

servelet:

```
model.addAttribute("test", "testing...");
```

html template:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
  [[${test}]]
  [(${test})]
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

generated output:

```
<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/
  'testing...'
  [(${test})]
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

So, escaped expression `[[ ]]` works, but unescaped expression `[( )]` doesn't. I have a need to generate js conditionally, and there's no "easy" workaround, so this would've been very helpful. Has anyone been able to get this to work? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, i can't reproduce this. I've tried Thymeleaf 3.0.1, 3.0.2 and 3.0.3 (with Spring 4 dialect although without Spring Boot) and they all work fine.

Comment: @RoToRa thank you, i figured it had to do with the dependencies. i got it to work, i'll post the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it to work with Spring Boot with the following four dependencies, all four being required (I'm using the latest versions currently available):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps.